# UnicodeDecodeError sending mail Django

Tags: python, django, encoding

I'm trying to send email (doesn't matter what includes) using `send_mail` function from `django.core.mail` and it shows me this error all the time:

I'm using **Python 3.6.4** and **Django 2.0.7**

> UnicodeDecodeError at /mail
>   'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 8: invalid continuation byte

Whole error:

```
Internal Server Error: /mail
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\RZECZY\mystuff\PYTHON\DJANGO\bank\banking\views.py", line 208, in sendSimpleEmail
    send_mail(subject='asda', message='asdas', from_email='champ3r@gmail.com', recipient_list=['kamil-wyszynski@wp.pl'])
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 294, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 54, in open
    connection_params = {'local_hostname': DNS_NAME.get_fqdn()}
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\utils.py", line 16, in get_fqdn
    self._fqdn = socket.getfqdn()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 8: invalid continuation byte
```

Here's my `vies.py` file:

```
def sendSimpleEmail(request):
    send_mail(subject='asda', message='asdas', from_email='example@test.com', recipient_list=['example2@test.com'])
    return redirect('home')
```

and the `setting.py` file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smpt.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'test'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question and give us the full traceback, instead of the error message alone? Also: which version of python are you using?

Comment: This is [a bug in Python on Windows](https://bugs.python.org/issue26227). See also https://bugs.python.org/issue26226 .